# Python Requests problem self._store[key.lower()][1]

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
url = "url"
payload="payload"
headers= headers
response = requests.request("POST",url, headers=headers, data=payload)
authCode = response.headers['authentication]

wurl = "wurl"
wpayload = "wpayload"
wheaders = {
       'Cookie': 'Cookie',
       'User-Agent: 'User-Agent',
       'Authentication' : authCode,
        }

wresponse = requests.request("POST",wurl, headers=wheaders, data=wpayload)
```

Hello, I wrote a program like this using the Python Requests module. The problem is that I can get the Authentication code from the headers part of the program first and then I can use it. But I cannot get the data I want from the data in the 2nd wresponse part. The error code is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\requeststest\app.py", line 30, in <module>
    getdata = wresponse.headers['Id']
  File "C:\Users\Alp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'id'
```

Although I have ID information in the data I receive, when I try to get ID information, I get this error. But in the first request, I was able to get the authentication code from the headers in the same way. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request is a CaseInsensitiveDict

```
type(wresponse.headers)
<class 'requests.structures.CaseInsensitiveDict'>
```

Much better to get items from this constructed dicts with `get` method.

```
wresponse = requests.get('https://www.google.es')
wresponse.headers
{'Date': 'Fri, 15 Jan 2021 21:39:46 GMT', 'Expires': '-1', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1', 'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Server': 'gws', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Set-Cookie': 'NID=207=gnRg4009rRe7v_PKYtq-3lb3ouJVNAvRpV7VsORkV2OSMkEyb_2s4GGhMIGIST9yN6ecbIzmFVbuGxXUn9mB5ourXONKakngjf4BZ_K31C4908P_VJCzPitnW-LliA-jZZb0vwQwPWhkrGyTnd8tqhZsmh0z1ftxKwvPURJyzdw; expires=Sat, 17-Jul-2021 21:39:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.es; HttpOnly', 'Alt-Svc': 'h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}

wresponse.headers.get('Date')
'Fri, 15 Jan 2021 21:39:46 GMT'
```

However your error is that `Id` key doesn't exists.
Try with `wresponse.headers.keys()` or `print(wresponse.headers)`  and verify!

Good luck!